# Digits Python Determination

Tags: python

I have a function that takes as a user input float parameter. I need to determine the number of digits that this parameter has to the right of the decimal place. I've tried the following but it doesn't work in the function. Any alternatives?

```
def x(x,y,minp):
    delta = ( ( y - x)/ minp ) * 10
    return delta
```

Essentially, I am writing a function to compute the delta of 2 values that has a multiplier associated with it. But the delta changes with the minimum increment I specify in `minp`. \

So for example, if x=100, and y=90, and minp=1, then the above should equal 100. The problem arises when i have decimals for y and x.

any ideas?

EDIT:

So the problem is that if say `x = 99.10`, `y=99.0`, and `minp=0.01`, i get `99.99999999999432`.

I tried:

```
delta = ( ( 99.1 - 99.0 )/ 0.01 ) * 10
dec = decimal.Decimal( 0.01  )
rounding = dec.as_tuple().exponent
round(delta,rounding)
```

above returns `0.0`...

Comment: Floating points will very often give you surprising results for things like this. You should either accept something like a `Decimal` type on input or try to give an error you're willing to approximate to.

Comment: what problem arises?

Comment: Something like the fact `0.1` actually has 55 decimal places after the zero, when rounded to the nearest double-precision floating point number (aka `float`).

Comment: see my above edits, i've given a more structured example

Comment: i was thinking of first converting the `minp` parameter to a string, and then do regrex to determine the number of digits to the right of the decimal, but I don't how to do regrex on that. any ideas on that front?

Comment: That's not the problem. You just are doing inexact maths. Using decimals would work, but you're using them wrongly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your numbers to be rounded exactly to a decimal digit (this is typically the wrong way to deal with precision issues), you need to store them as `Decimal`s:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def x(x, y, minp):
    delta = ( ( y - x)/ minp ) * 10
    return delta

result = x(Decimal("99.1"), Decimal("99.0"), Decimal("0.01"))

result
#>>> Decimal('-1.0E+2')

float(result)
#>>> -100.0
```

This is actually a really poor way to do almost anything but currency. Decimal maths only has the property that it *prints* more nicely, it's not inherently more exact.

Instead, you'd typically want either

- To account for the errors in precision properly, normally by using error bounds and a good understanding of floating point.
- To have no errors at all:

  ```
  from fractions import Fraction

  def x(x, y, minp):
      delta = ( ( y - x)/ minp ) * 10
      return delta

  result = x(Fraction("99.1"), Fraction("99.0"), Fraction("0.01"))

  result
  #>>> Fraction(-100, 1)

  float(result)
  #>>> -100.0
  ```

  This is useful even within a function:

  ```
  from fractions import Fraction

  def x(x, y, minp):
      x = Fraction(x)
      y = Fraction(y)
      minp = Fraction(minp)

      delta = ( ( y - x)/ minp ) * 10
      return float(delta)

  result = x(99.1, 99.0, 0.01)

  result
  #>>> -99.99999999999432

  float(result)
  #>>> -99.99999999999432
  ```

  because even though you have imprecise input and output, the *intermediaries* are precise. In this case it didn't help because the problem was with the input, not the intermediaries.

The second option is slow, so it's almost always better to actually deal with errors. It's not like science gives you infinitely precise measurements anyway.